# FormData submit NodeJS returns 503 unavailable

Tags: node.js, heroku, multer

I'm trying to deploy my application to Heroku (as usual) and I keep getting **503 Service Unavailable**  when trying to upload anything through my router handler (Multer)!

it's not related to any packages since I tried different projects with and without multer and the same return

Comment: Hello, have you solved it? same error for me. on local works, on heroku 503. Tried also multer-s3, without using disk storage. same thing.

Comment: The problem was still there with Heroku even after I emailed them and gave them the source code. They couldn't fix it. So, I switched to Digital Ocean and everything got better

Answer (score 0):

Hi @Mahmoud Nasr,
Kindly run the nodejs code locally in system and check for any issues.

> If it works then the issue is with Heroku server configurations or the
> server is not available.
>
> If it not working in local in the first place kindly update the snippet,
> let's figure it out.

Regards,
Muhamed

Comment: I already run the code locally and it works Locally and on Azure and Google Run!

Comment: also you can try it yourself by POST ANY Form data with any file to any Heroku domain it will return 503

Comment: if you use mutler lib that uses disk path then try to avoid that by using in-memory file hold ref -https://github.com/expressjs/multer#memorystorage 

The issue with the above approach is, that we can only handle the small files with less frequency.

if you want to handle large files or high-frequency files try storing data into some open cloud storage then try to process by parts 

Kindly try the above one and revert back

Comment: it's not related to project or lib. for example make a POST req to https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/ with form data with any file even 1kb and it will return 503

Comment: I tried and able to upload file upto 5KB via postman
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
curl Ref- ------------------------------------------------------------------

curl --location --request POST 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/' \
--form 'data=@"/C:/Users/HP/Downloads/output-onlinefiletools (5KB File).txt"'

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

more than 5KB I observe inconsistent 503 I believe there is platform constraint w.r.t. plans

Comment: The weirdest thing is that I have Heroku perineum and received this message. I contacted Heroku, and they do not believe that the issue is from the routing system. They keep telling me to review your code! even though this problem happens without my domain!

Comment: May the error is not form routing system and there are many error thats abstracted by their 503 common error response kindly I would recommend to check the logs and compare it with the docs so that we may get some idea